# Ionic 3 google maps height proportional to screen size

Tags: css, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to get the higher of google maps to fill the full height of the screen (no matter the size of the phone) plus a fixed height button at the very bottom. I'm using `Ionic 3`.

Right now on `iPhone 5` it looks perfect, which on `iPhone X` (bigger screen) the map is way too big. `iPhone 6` is just in the middle (not good).

```
<ion-content no-bounce>
  <div class="container">
    <ion-list class="autocomplete-list">
      <ion-item class="autocomplete-class" type="text" placeholder="Pick an address">{{this.geocoding.locationObject}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <div #map id="map"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonContainerSafeArea">
    <button (click)="next()" class="addLocationButton">Next</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

My CSS is:

```
.container {
    margin-bottom: constant(safe-area-inset-bottom);
    margin-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    widows: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #map {
    margin-bottom: constant(safe-area-inset-bottom);
    margin-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
    position: fixed;
    top: 11%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 74.9%;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .addLocationButton {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index : 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: $font-family-buttons;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: $red-color;
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  .buttonContainerSafeArea {
    margin-bottom: constant(safe-area-inset-bottom);
    margin-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code for full height google map.

### ts

```
height : string;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public alertCtrl:AlertController) 
{
    this.height = (document.documentElement.clientHeight-15)+"px";
}
```

### html

```
<ion-content>
    <div #map id="map" [style.width]="'100%'" [style.height]="height"></div>
    <div class="buttonContainerSafeArea">
        <button (click)="next()" class="addLocationButton">Next</button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

From `document.documentElement.clientHeight` you have to minus button height. If you add more element at top you have to also minus height of those element too.

Comment: Thanks, works partly, it's just now I need to subtract the navbar, tabs and input field from this value, and they are different for different iphone sizes. Any idea how to get those sizes too? Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to major it manually and minus it. That size i think same in all devices

Comment: I don't think it's the same, as using the same "minus" value gives very different sizes from iPhone 5 to iPhone 7plus.

Comment: Your method is working. Any idea how to represent this in HTML code: "#map:after {margin: 20px}". [style.margin-top]="topDisplacement" might affect the whole #map.

Comment: Means you have to leave margin from top?

Comment: Yes, but I need to set this margin programmatically from JS if a certain condition is met, so I can't sent it directly from CSS.